# This code reads the database and populates the table but the columns do not match the data

Tags: java, swing, jtable

The columns don't match up even though it is the same column order as the database (MS Access)

I am still learning so please help

```
DBConnect db = new DBConnect();
try {
    ResultSet rs = db.queryTbl("SELECT * FROM tblCourses");
    while (tblCourses.getRowCount() > 0) {
        ((DefaultTableModel) tblCourses.getModel()).removeRow(0);
    }
    int columns = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
    while (rs.next()) {
        Object[] row = new Object[columns];
        for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
            row[i - 1] = rs.getObject(i);
        }
        ((DefaultTableModel) tblCourses.getModel()).insertRow(rs.getRow() - 1, row);
    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
}
```

Comment: Please add some more information to you question. For example: What the table looks like, the output you receive and the output you expect.

Comment: So the jtable has the headings (CourseID, CourseName, Province, Rating, SlopeRating, NumHoles, EmailAddress, PhoneNum) which is in the same order as the database. However when the code is run, the data shows in the incorrect column in this order (CourseName, Province, SlopeRating, NumHoles, CourseID, EmailAddress, PhoneNum, Rating)


AKA
Column (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
Data (1, 2, 4, 5, 0, 6, 7, 3)

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).